# Mod_rewrite on Amazon S3

Tags: mod-rewrite, amazon-s3

Is it possible to use mod_rewrite on Amazon S3?

```
www.example.com/about.html -> mybucket.s3.amazon.com/index.html
www.example.com/welcome.html -> mybucket.s3.amazon.com/index.html
www.example.com/contact.html -> mybucket.s3.amazon.com/index.html
```

Thanks!

Comment: How come you haven't just got a CNAME pointing at your S3 bucket?

Comment: @PiersKarsenbarg Can you say more about what you were thinking here? A CNAME will bind a particular host to the bucket host -- how does this help with mod_rewrite config? The user isn't just asking to transfer requests from a.com/a to b.com/a; they want a.com/a -> b.com/p

Answer (score 1):

The examples you shared here don't require rewriterules on amazon s3 itself, the redirections all happen on the `www.example.com` site: so either in `.htaccess` or `vhost` conf or `httpd.conf`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(about|welcome|contact)\.html$ http://mybucket.s3.amazon.com/index.html [R,L]
```

Granted, this will change the URL shown in the browser. If you want to do this without it being so apparent to the end user, then as @piers says, you will need to [add a cname for your bucket on s3](http://imtips.co/customizing-amazon-s3-urls-with-cname.html). and then reference/link to these files at your new `http://mybucketalias.example.com/index.html` address.